# Converting a while loop to a for loop in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

It seems like a simple conversion, but I can't seem to find the syntax for it.

```
i = start
while(if step > 0 then i < end else i > end)
  array.push i
  i += step
```

start, end, and step are a signed integers

Comment: start, end, and step are a signed integers

Comment: Oh, "signed integers", right. But that wan't my question. If `step` is `1` and `start` is `0` and `end` is `0` you'll end up in an infinite loop. So it does matter how those are initialized before the loop, and this may be important for converting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [CofeeScript page on loops](http://coffeescript.org/#loops).  But the way to do this in CoffeeScript is with a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) iterating over a range:

```
(array.push i for i in [start...end] by step)
```

But note that a list comprehension returns a value.  For instance, given this code:

```
start = 10
end = 5
step = -2
array = []
(array.push i for i in [start...end] by step)
```

The variable `array` winds up with the value `[10,8,6]`, as expected, but since `push` returns the new length of the array it just pushed onto, the *return value* of that last statement - which will be returned if it's the last thing in a function, or printed if you enter the above at the REPL, etc. - is `[1, 2, 3]`.

**EDIT** So it would be better, as noted below, to just construct the array with the list comprehension in the first place:

```
array = (i for i in [start...end] by step)
```

When building a range, note that `...` yields an exclusive range in terms of the right endpoint, while `..` yields an inclusive one.  So `[1..5]` includes 5 in the list, while `[1...5]` stops at 4.

Also, if you really find yourself needing the flexibility of the C-style `for` loop, you can always embed some literal JavaScript in your CoffeeScript by wrapping it in backticks (`...`):

```
`for (i=start; (step > 0 && i < end) || (step < 0 && i > end); i+=step) {
     array.push(i);
 }`
```

Comment: that is the equivalent of

while(if step > 0 then i <= end else i >= end)

but, I need

while(if step > 0 then i < end else i > end)

Comment: @user842893 - change the dots in the range.  [a..b] is inclusive, [a...b] is exclusive.  I'll edit.

Comment: I just would like the fine control of the while loop, in the cleaner syntax of the for loop. I don't know if coffee script allows that.

Comment: @user842893 - you can always break into native JavaScript for the extra flexibility if you really need it somewhere.  Added an example of that, too.

Comment: @MarkReed Your solution will work, but as you said, the loop returns a value. You take out the `array.push` and use the return value of the loop directly. `array = (i for i in [start...end] by step)`.

Answer (score 2):

This may do what you want, assuming that you want the numbers from `start` to `end` as items in the `array` variable:

```
array = (i for i in [start...end])
```